# Smart Device Project In visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I need to create a smart device project. But I cant't find the 'smart device' project type in vs 2010. How to enable this project type in VS 2010. There is any additional features to be installed.? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the answer to the question [ETA on Smart Device Projects for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775639/eta-on-smart-device-projects-for-visual-studio-2010), this project type is no longer supported in Visual Studio 2010.

> Microsoft's [current public statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t(VS.100).aspx) says that, apart from Windows Phone 7 development, there will not be Smart Device Application Development added to Visual Studio 2010.